# Open Sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was wondering what the general form of an open set is in the real numbers. Is it just an interval of the form $(a,b)$; $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: More precisely, countable union of such sets.

Comment: ok, so any such interval of the above form, taking a countable union of that would give us an open set? Can't we also say  the same when we have a closed interval as well?

Comment: that's a different q to the q you asked

Comment: the big issue is sets of the form (a,b] or [a,b) - often called clopen sets.

Comment: @user1314; no-one is making you do anything.

Comment: ok, i will have a look at clopen sets and try to make some sense

Comment: no i just wanted to know whether to post another question, since i had a similar experience on Physics stack exchange where I couldnt post multiple questions

Comment: that's physics for you.

Comment: yeah, plus it takes a lot longer than normal to get your questions answered, whereas in maths it is frighteningly quick,

Comment: $(0,.5)\cup(.5,1)=(0,1)\setminus\{.5\}$ is also open, by the way. It's an example of a set that is dense in $(0,1)$ but not equal to $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: (a,b] and [a,b) are not clopen sets.

Comment: @zarathustra From Wikipedia itself: In topology, *a clopen set (a portmanteau of closed-open set) in a topological space is a set which is* **both open and closed**.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: well, $(a,b]$ is **neither** open **nor** closed.

Comment: well, its complement is both open and closed then. @zarathustra;

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: the sequence $a+\frac1{n}$ of points from this interval converges to $a$, which is not in it. So it is not closed. Moreover, any ball around $b$ intersects the complement of $(a,b]$, so it is not open either.

Comment: @zarathustra; i found this example: http://www.quora.com/In-laymans-terms-what-is-a-clopen-set, but i think i still prefer my definition.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: the answer there is also wrong ("Another intuitive understanding of a clopen set is a set that has an empty boundary.", $(a,b)$ has an empty boundary but is not closed, so not clopen). You can use the definition you want, as long as you don't confuse some other people who actually try to understand.

Comment: @zarathustra; thanks - i will, i'm writing a book at the moment, i think i'll try and use it in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of open intervals of the type $(a,b)$ is a basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. This means that all open sets of this topology can be written as countable unions or finite intersections of open intervals.

As an exercise, you can take $a<b<c$ and search all the open sets that you can define from these three points; e.g.
$(a,b) \cup (b,c)$ is a finite union and it's open.

Also the set that you can obtain as countable union of the countable family of intervals $\{(a,kb): k \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$ is open, and note that it is  $(a,+\infty)$.

And, if you want to see that infinite intersections can give not open sets, you can use the family $\{(a-\frac{b}{k},a+\frac{c}{k}): k \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$ whose union is $(a-b,a+c)$  but  the intersection is the set $\{a\}$. 
But, note that any **finite** intersection of open intervals gives an open set. A special case is $(a,b) \cap (b,c)=\emptyset$ that is open.

Answer (score 1):

This has been stated in the comments. 
Consider $A=(1,2)\cup(3,4)$.
$x\in A$ implies $x\in (1,2)$ or $(3,4)$. Suppose $x\in (1,2)$. As $(1,2)$ is open, $ \exists \epsilon>0 \text{ such that } B(x,\epsilon)\subset (1,2)\subset A$. Similarly, consider the case when $x\in (3,4)$. So, $A$ is open.

In other words, open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ need not be in the form of an interval.

Comment: oh ok, but every open set is essentially a countable union of open intervals. Is that a valid definition that I can use?

Comment: Open intervals form a base of $\mathbb R$ and it's enough to consider these with rational endpoints.

Comment: The empty set $\phi$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not a countable union of open intervals. I don't really know further, sorry. @LeonAragones, I realized that after writing my comment.

Comment: Here countable probably means countable or finite (maybe empty).

Comment: ok that is very helpful!. Just one last question, not directly related to open sets but rather Borel sigma algebras, I know that every interval can in fact be written as a countable union  of closed intervals and then this would show that any sigma algebra generated by the family of these closed intervals would contain the Borel sigma algebra,  but how do I show that a closed interval is a Borel Set.

Answer (score 0):

We define a primitive open set on the reals ($\mathbb{R}$) as:

$$a,b,x\in \mathbb{R} : a<x<b$$

and we write $(a,b)$.

A union of two open sets is also open. Let $A$ and $B$ be two open sets, their union is open whether $A\cap B=\emptyset$ or not. Any finite union of primitive open sets is open.

Any countable union of open sets is also open, and it is possible for an uncountable union of open sets to be open, for example:

$$A_n=(x,1-x);\; x\in\mathbb{R},0\lt x\lt\frac{1}{2}$$

The union is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Furthermore, any finite intersection of such opens is again open.

Comment: ok sorry for this last question, so can we have open sets in the real line which are not of this form? Might sound like a really stupid question

Comment: No, because we said what the open sets are, and we said what the permitted operations on these open sets are which keep them open.

Comment: ok, now that makes sense to me, thank you